# Как лучше сделать картинку?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
<sub>(источник: [freefrontend.com](https://freefrontend.com/assets/img/css-cards/blog-card-with-hover-state.jpg))</sub>

Допустим есть блог куда добавляются посты в виде таких вот карточек. В данном случае как лучше сделать картинку через фон или img? Фоном мне кажется задать удобнее но правильно ли это?(Картинка в данном случае играет не декоративную роль а несет информацию о посте). Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Я бы делал фоном.

Comment: Если вы хотите, что бы картинка индексировалась поисковыми роботами, то тогда применяйте тэг `<img>` - если же, данная картинка не играет семантической роли, тогда background

Comment: Но по-хорошему, в настройке поста пользователь должен это задавать как `background` - а не как img

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич я не знал про индексацию поисковиками

Comment: Это касается seo непосредственно. А в чем же разница тогда по вашему?)

Comment: background проще всего, но это неправильно, инлайновых стилей, как и скриптов не должно быть на сайте вообще. Поэтому считаю что только картинкой вставлять стоит.

Comment: `Картинка в данном случае играет не декоративную роль а несет информацию о посте`. вы сами ответили на свой вопрос. ставьте тегом.

Answer (score 2):

Показать проще чем болталогию разводить

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.item {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 310px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow:4px 4px 20px;
}

.darkness {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.description {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.description-header,
.description-footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}

.description-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: #fbfbfb;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: sans;
  text-align: center;
}

.description-header .line {
  width: 40%;
  height: 1px;
  background: gold;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.description-header p {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 100;
  width: 60%;
  font-style: italic;
}

i.fa {
  color: #fbfbfb;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: gold;
  padding-right: 4px;
}

.description-footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.description-footer div {
  padding: 12px;
}

.description-footer span {
  color: #fbfbfb;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="item">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://img.wallpaper.sc/applewatch/images/312x390/applewatch-312x390-photoface-wallpaper_00239.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="darkness"></div>
  <div class="description">
    <div class="description-header">
      <h2>spring fever</h2>
      <div class="line"></div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="description-footer">
      <div>
        <span><i class="fa fa-comment-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>12</span>
        <span><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>03.12.2015</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```